# Oracle Link Query returning strange values

Tags: sql, t-sql, linked-server, pass-through

I am developing the Store procedure which queries the Oracle Link Server and returning values.
If I copy the statement which is printed on the screen and run on the Oracle SQL Developer, it returns the figure correctly.

But when I run that one as the link query, it returns wrong figure.  I am completely lost.

```
DECLARE @MDX NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @MDX = dbo.fnCrseReviewDiversityDataStarts(117) 
Set @stmt = 'SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(ORA_Link, ''' + REPLACE(@MDX, '''', '''''') + ''')'
PRINT @MDX

EXEC (@stmt)
```

Please ignore the above SQL Statements.  I just used the following sqls directly and it's not working.  I found out that months_between function is not working as it works in OracleServer.

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(ORA_LINK, 'select t2.s_studentreference "Student reference",
to_char(t3.e_start,''YYYY'') "Start",
t1.p_dob,
''31-Aug-''||to_char(t3.e_start,''YYYY'') "StartDate",
months_between(t1.p_dob,''31-Aug-''||to_char(t3.e_start,''YYYY'')) "DifferenceMonths"    
from capd_student t2,capd_person t1,capd_moduleenrolment t3 
where t2.s_id(+)=t1.p_id and (t3.e_student=t1.p_id) and (t3.e_reference=to_char(1109315)) 
and t3.e_status = ''L'''
);
```

Comment: please post the code of the sp

Comment: I uploaded the codes aF.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answers.

In Oracle, if we use '01-AUG-2010', it recognizes automatically as a date.

But, in Pass through query, we have to use to_date('01-AUG-2010', 'DD-MON-YYYY') and explicitly needs to tell that this is a date.

I don't know why but Interesting one.  If you know an answer, please let me know.  Thanks very much all.